# Getting magento stores to show up in google search

Tags: magento2

My store names do not show up in google search. I have multiple stores: How do I get them to show up. For example if I have a store on magento 2 called fixup, when person searches for fix up, I want the store called fixup on my magento to show in results.

Comment: this is the work of seo

Answer (score 0):

you should definitely check [SEO Best Practices](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/seo-best-practices.html) at Magento docs.
That's a really good point to start. You have to allow search engine robots to index your store and provide some meta data.

After setting up your sitemap, you can even submit it to [google search console](https://search.google.com/search-console/about).